# Create general purpose WinWaitActive in AutoIT

Tags: automation, autoit

I'm thinking of using the WinWaitActive function to play a sound file every time the currently active program finished a task (ie. After Effect finished rendering, Word finished saving, etc.).

From what I know about WinWaitActive, I'll need to write a script for each internal process of each application. That's a huge amount of automation scripts. Is there any way to make a single script that will work with all programs and processes?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include<array.au3>
Global $window_Array[1]

$window = "dokument - wordpad"
checkWin()

;ConsoleWrite(_ArrayToString($window_Array, @CR))

Func checkWin()
    Global $var = WinList()
    For $i = 1 To $var[0][0]
        If $var[$i][0] <> "" Then _ArrayAdd($window_Array, $var[$i][0])
        Next
    If _ArraySearch($window_Array, $window, 0, 0, 0) <> - 1 Then
        MsgBox(0, "", "Found!")
    Else
        MsgBox(0, "", "Not Found!")
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>checkWin
```